# Error with my mint function

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, nft, mint

i have differents parts of code to call a mint function.

the parts are this

2 modifiers

```
modifier mintCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(_mintAmount > 0 && _mintAmount <= maxMintAmountPerTx, "Invalid mint amount!");
    require(supply.current() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "Max supply exceeded!");
    _;
  }

    modifier mintCompliancePresale(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(_mintAmount > 0 && _mintAmount <= maxMintAmountPerTx, "Invalid mint amount!");
    require(supply.current() + _mintAmount <= maxPresaleSupply, "Max supply exceeded!");
    _;
  }
```

One is for normal mint, and the other one is for presale minting only.

And that connects with my mint functions.

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount) {
      require(!paused, "The contract is paused!");
      require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds!");

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(onlyWhitelisted == true) {
            require(isWhitelisted(msg.sender), "user is not whitelisted");
    }
    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "insufficient funds");
    }

    _mintLoop(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
} 

    function presaleMint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliancePresale(_mintAmount) {
      require(!paused, "The contract is paused!");
      require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds!");

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(onlyWhitelisted == true) {
            require(isWhitelisted(msg.sender), "user is not whitelisted");
    }
    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "insufficient funds");
    }

    _mintLoop(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
}
```

2 functions, one for normal mint and another one for presale minting.

and that connects with my mint loop

```
 function _mintLoop(address _receiver, uint256 _mintAmount) internal {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _mintAmount; i++) {
      supply.increment();
      _safeMint(_receiver, supply.current());
    }
  }
```

Now, my question is how can i improve the 2 modifiers and 2 mint functions in just 1 modifier and 1 minting function? Is it possible to do?

I dont think 2 modifiers and 2 minting functions have sense. It works, but i think there is an error inside it.